# Multiband to single band raster

Tags: qgis, raster, multi-band

Is there a tool that is able to transform a multi-band image to single band rasters? I usually use the raster calculator within the modeler to do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `gdal_translate` from the new workflow, which is under:

```
Raster > Conversion > Rearrange bands...
```

You won't be able to select the pencil as in the past, but you can select only the band you need from the UI. You also get the python code in case you want to use it in pyqgis:

```
gdal_translate "path/to/raster.tif" -b 1 "path/to/result.tif"
```

To get band 2, replace `-b 1` with `-b 2` etc.

---

Note: you may need to enable the **GdalTools** plugin.

Comment: If you use VRT as the outputformat you will get something like the first example in http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html. Then you need just edit the  <SourceBand>1</SourceBand> line for selecting other bands.

Comment: @Pimpel - Most welcome! Glad it worked :)

Comment: Is it me or did they remove the pencil icon in Qgis > 3.4 ?

Comment: @Kantan - It's not you, this has been an issue which has been reported: [https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15090](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15090)

Comment: Thanks @Joseph! Unfortunately, it was rejected, so I guess only the raster calculator trick works now.

Comment: Is there a way to do this to extract all the bands? I have a band for every day of the year