# Filtering data on QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, filter, band

I have a raster displaying anchoring intensity in the Mediterranean Sea.  As you can see in the first screenshot, there are two different classes (pink and dark pink). I would like to get rid of the grey part. I tried to filter it based on the bands value for the grey part (raster calculator, in screenshot). However, when I do that, I lose the difference in intensities between my two main categories (pink colours) and I only have presence/absence then (see attached screenshot). Do you know how I could solve that issue ? [image]

Comment: It looks like you are storing these data in a 4 band raster.  You could convert that to a single band raster with values like 1 = low density anchorage, 2 = high density anchorage, gray = NoData.  They you can easily filter out the view of NoData.  Maybe start here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237149/multiband-to-single-band-raster or this tool maybe:  https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/